# Can't get resource in json, because of a reserved codeword used in the struct

Tags: python, json, reserved-words

I have this json:

```
{
'update_id': 30362315,
'callback_query': {
    'inline_message_id': '',
    'from': {
        'username': u 'simone989',
        'first_name': u 'Simone',
        'last_name': '',
        'type': '',
        'id': 46806104
    }....
```

To get a parameter in the JSON, I use:

```
update_id.callback_query.from.id
```

but "from" is a reserved keyword.

I can't modify the struct of the JSON.

Comment: How are you using the dot notation? Python does not allow that syntax on json objects so pretty sure your error is relating to you using that more than the name itself. add the actual error traceback

Comment: Do you get error message ? Show it in question. You can use `from` as object element ie. `self.from`

Comment: "I have this json:" => this is __not__ a "json", it's a Python `dict`. JSON is a text format, not a type.

Answer (score 3):

You can use square brackets:

```
update_id.callback_query['from'].id
```

Comment: print update.callback_query['from'].id
return 'from'

Answer (score 2):

Python does not allow you to navigate in JSON structs using the `.` operator.

You will have to specify all members using the indexing operator:

```
print(data["update_id"])
print(data["callback_query"]["from"]["id"])
```

Comment: I think this is the actual solution.

Comment: return only 'from'

Comment: @simone989 Sorry I dont really understand what you are saying.

Comment: "Python does not allow you to navigate in JSON structs" => Actually there's __nothing__ like a "JSON struct" in Python.  JSON is a text format, and what we're talking here is a plain old Python `dict`.